# How skip required validation on image file type field if old image exist in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5

How stop or ignore image file type field validation if old image exist in Laravel 5.5

I have want to need skip required validation if old image exist.

```
<form name="">
<input type="file" name="profile_image" />
<input type="hidden" name="old_profile_image" value="xyz.jpg"/>
</form>


$validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'profile_image' => 'required|file|mime:gif,jpeg,jpg',
]);
```

Comment: Where you are checking old image? In DB or on file system.

Comment: @abid can you please share how you are checking old image ? in DB or file?

Comment: 'profile_image' => 'required|require_if:old_profile_image,'==',""|file|mime:gif,jpeg,jpg',